# Wordpress menu CSS Classes is not working

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I want to change the color of  one of the tabs of the menu bar in Wordpress using menu CSS Classes, I added the class name in my style file, but when I add the class name in the CSS Classes in the Admin->Menu page it's not working. that's the class name in the style file it's very simple.

```
.red{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to apply to the child `a` tag (I believe the class is added to the outside `<li>` element by WP - view source to confirm).

```
li.red a {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Can you link to your implementation? It's working for me in a WP 3.6 install in my staging area

Comment: Because of class inheritance, and the way your stylesheet is written, the `.red` class is being overridden. Instead of simple `.red` declaration, try: `.navbar .nav > li.red > a { color: #ff0000; }` which will override the declaration/selector in place for `.navbar .nav > li > a {..}`

Comment: It change's the whole website, take a look because I will undo.

Comment: My bad, I uploaded a wrong CSS file. It's working now Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you added a class name red to tag `<li>`, you should code it with two option.

Option 1:

```
.red{
    color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

Option 2:

level parent to class `red`

```
level_parent .red { color: #ff0000; }
```